# Corda notary prevention in double spending,how to check it?

Tags: corda, notary

I need to check how the notary prevents the double spending in the Obligation Cordapp. I started the web server UI at the localhost ports and performed some multiple transactions and when I checked the notary's log ,I found this:

**[WARN ] 2020-06-24T08:29:33,484Z [Notary request queue processor] transactions.PersistentUniquenessProvider. - Unable to notarise: One or more input states or referenced states have already been used as input states in other transactions. Conflicting state count: 1, consumption details:
7CF1BCA8EDF25F0602BBEDF8AD41FD60336F65EAC09C5326478A4CB7CD620579(0) -> StateConsumptionDetails(hashOfTransactionId=46552C5CE153712B65585A75C4D165CD4A05304564C8797ACEF317DCD925B72E, type=INPUT_STATE).
To find out if any of the conflicting transactions have been generated by this node you can use the hashLookup Corda shell command. [errorCode=1g4005y, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5-RC02/1g4005y]
net.corda.core.internal.notary.NotaryInternalException: Unable to notarise: One or more input states or referenced states have already been used as input states in other transactions. Conflicting state count: 1, consumption details:
7CF1BCA8EDF25F0602BBEDF8AD41FD60336F65EAC09C5326478A4CB7CD620579(0) -> StateConsumptionDetails(hashOfTransactionId=46552C5CE153712B65585A75C4D165CD4A05304564C8797ACEF317DCD925B72E, type=INPUT_STATE).
To find out if any of the conflicting transactions have been generated by this node you can use the hashLookup Corda shell command.**

I performed hashLookup on the invalid txId and found this :

hashLookup 46552C5CE153712B65585A75C4D165CD4A05304564C8797ACEF317DCD925B72E
Found a matching transaction with Id: A86E3ECE4EC12A487E413E2BDAB9D88BFEBCB418FA0224189DE0C72BBBD34B12

I believe this is how notary has stopped the double spending. But I am unable to recreate that testing.Can someone tell me what possible input transaction has led to this error.I mean what test case can lead to this testing of double spend that is stopped by notary?

Answer (score 0):

A notary is a network service that provides uniqueness consensus by attesting that, for a given transaction, it has not already signed other transactions that consumes any of the proposed transaction’s input states.

In other words, the notary will keep track of all the input states (only stores their hashes, not the real state) that are used in transactions, so when someone is trying to use these already-spent inputs, the notary will reject the transaction.

Hence, preventing the double spend.